# AngularJS Displays HTML Unicode from backend in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, backend

I am trying to display characters from different languages on my screen. These characters are generated by a csv file which is convert to JSON format as follows

```
{
"id": 32,
"name": "Hindi",
"csv": [
    {
        "keycode": "1",
        "unicode": "\u0D15",
        "chakra": "1"
    },
    {
        "keycode": "1",
        "unicode": "\u0D15",
        "chakra": "1"
    },
    {
        "keycode": "1",
        "unicode": "\u0D15",
        "chakra": "1"
    }
]
}
```

I am seeing the html unicodes displayed on the screen though I am using $sce.trustAshtml() for the unicode values via filter. Here is my angularJS code.

controller :

```
app.controller("KeyboardController", [
"$scope", "Restangular", "LanguageModel", "KeyboardModel", "$sce", function($scope, Restangular, LanguageModel, KeyboardModel, $sce) {
  var languageResource;
  $scope.languages = LanguageModel.getAll();
  languageResource = Restangular.one("languages");
  angular.element("#chakra").css("display", "none");
  languageResource.getList("all").then(function(languageobject) {
    LanguageModel.addAll(languageobject);
    KeyboardModel.addlanguage(languageobject);
    $scope.onscreen = KeyboardModel.getallkeys();
    $scope.firstmaintablekeys = KeyboardModel.maintablelayout1();
  });
}
```

]);

keyboardModel : service.

```
app.factory("KeyboardModel", function() {
var KeyboardModel;
KeyboardModel = function() {
  this.keys = [];
  this.key = [];
  this.keyid = {};
  this.languageobject = {};
};
KeyboardModel.prototype = {
  addlanguage: function(languageobject) {
    this.languageobject = languageobject;
  },
  getallkeys: function() {
    var currentlanguage, div, grouped, i, mod, totalrows;
    currentlanguage = this.languageobject[1];
    totalrows = currentlanguage.csv.length;
    grouped = [];
    i = 0;
    while (i < totalrows) {
      div = Math.floor(i / 5);
      mod = i % 5;
      if (mod === 0) {
        grouped[div] = [];
      }
      grouped[div][mod] = currentlanguage.csv[i];
      i++;
    }
    this.keys = grouped;
    return grouped;
  },
  maintablelayout1: function(language) {
    var i, table;
    i = 0;
    table = [];
    while (i < 4) {
      table[i] = this.keys[i];
      i++;
    }
    return table;
  }
};
return new KeyboardModel();
});
```

HTML :

```
  <div class="maintable1 frame1" ng-show="frame1">
    <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in firstmaintablekeys">
          <td ng-repeat="row in data" data-keycode="{{ row.keycode }}" data-chakra="{{ row.chakra }}" ng-mousedown="displaychakra(row.keycode, row.unicode, $event)" ng-mouseup="hidechakra()" ng-click="sharetext(row.unicode)">
            <span ng-bind-html="row.unicode | unsafeFilter"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Filter :

```
app.filter("unsafeFilter", function($sce) {
  return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
});
```

Am I missing something? Why do I get unicodes displayed instead of their corresponding values?

EDIT : I have been told its a server side issue. Here is my controller which reads the CSV file that contains the Unicodes.

```
class LanguagesController < ApplicationController

def index
end

def all
  availablelanguages = {
    :data => []
  }
  @language = Language.all.each do |eachlanguage|
    availablelanguages[:data] << {
      :id => eachlanguage.id,
      :name => eachlanguage.languagename,
      :csv => []
    }
    CSV.foreach(eachlanguage.path) do |row|
      availablelanguages[:data].each do |single|
        single[:csv] << {
          :keycode => row[0],
          :unicode => row[1],
          :chakra => row[2]
        }
      end
    end
    @data = JSON.pretty_generate(availablelanguages[:data])
  end
  render json: @data
end
end
```

Here is the screenshot of the JSON response generated. It adds an additional backlash to make the string literal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWW0g.png

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same recently. JSON returned unicode (Chinese). Didn't have to do any thing to decode it. Just insert this line in your header area.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```